# How to connect to database once app is uploaded to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I recently pushed my app to heroku and this app uses a mongodb atlas. It worked fine when I ran it on my localhost but when I pushed it to the heroku server, it give me this error:

```
2021-02-09T03:54:31.379532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-09T03:54:55.357747+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: Operation `todotitles.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
2021-02-09T03:54:55.357758+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:20)
2021-02-09T03:54:55.357758+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
2021-02-09T03:54:55.357759+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
2021-02-09T03:54:55.371677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=todolist-app101.herokuapp.com request_id=ba07cea3-44b2-4346-8cda-40b4c81fa1c3 fwd="110.54.169.178" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10043ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374468+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: /app/views/index.ejs:11
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374470+00:00 app[web.1]: 9|     <a class="site-title" href="/">ToDo App</a>
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374471+00:00 app[web.1]: 10|     <div class="main-list-container">
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374471+00:00 app[web.1]: >> 11|         <% todos.forEach((todos)=>{ %>
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374472+00:00 app[web.1]: 12|                 <form action="/removeList" class="list-container" method="POST">
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374473+00:00 app[web.1]: 13|                     <a href="/list/<%= todos._id %>" class="list-container-title"><%= todos.title %></a>
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374473+00:00 app[web.1]: 14|                     <button type="submit" name="removeList" value="<%= todos._id %>" class="deletebtn">�️</button>
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374474+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-09T03:54:55.374474+00:00 app[web.1]: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

I have made everything right, although I don't know why mongodb atlas doesnt seem to find my collection if I run heroku but on local host I can see my collections in the mongodb atlas Data. I dont know whats wrong with this.

Here is the app.js code:

```
let mongoServerPassword = process.env.MONGO_SERVER_PASSWORD
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin-cloyd:'+mongoServerPassword+'@todo-app.0pmsv.mongodb.net/toDoDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=>{
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
})
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
const TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:  {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
    },
})
const todo = mongoose.model('todo', TodoSchema)

const TodoTitleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        min: 1,
        max: 30,
    },
    content: [TodoSchema],
})
const todoTitle = mongoose.model('todoTitle', TodoTitleSchema)

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    todoTitle.find((err, todos)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            todos: todos,
        })
    })
})
app.post('/addNewList', (req,res)=>{
    let newList = todoTitle.insertMany({
        title: req.body.newList,
    })
    res.redirect('/')
})
app.get('/list/:todoID', (req,res)=>{
    let reqID = req.params.todoID;
    todoTitle.find({},(err, todos)=>{
        todoTitle.findOne({_id:reqID},(err, foundtodo)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            res.render('list.ejs', {
                todos: todos,
                todostitle: foundtodo.title,
                todocontent: foundtodo.content,
                todoID: foundtodo._id,
                foundtodo: foundtodo,
            })
        })   
    })
})

app.post('/addNewTodo', (req,res)=>{
    let newItem = new todo({name:req.body.newItem})
    let listtitle = req.body.listTitle;
    todoTitle.findOne({_id:listtitle},(err, foundtodo)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        foundtodo.content.push(newItem);
        foundtodo.save();
        res.redirect('/list/'+listtitle);
    })
})

app.post('/removeList',(req,res)=>{
    let listID = req.body.removeList;
    todoTitle.findOneAndDelete({_id:listID}, (err, foundlist)=>{
        if(err){console.log(err)};
        res.redirect('/');
    })
})
app.post('/removeTodo',(req,res)=>{
    let todoID = req.body.removeTodo;
    let listID = req.body.listID;
    todoTitle.findOneAndUpdate({_id: listID}, {$pull: {content: {_id: todoID}}}, (err, foundtodo)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.redirect('/list/'+listID);
    })
})
```

edit:
The app can't connect to the database when it's uploaded to heroku.

Comment: likely your production app is having issues connecting to your production database

Comment: thats what I was thinking too, but it works on my localhost, so it has really gotten me confused

Comment: probably has to do with your `MONGO_SERVER_PASSWORD` then

Comment: no, what Im trying to say is that even if I launch the app on just the localhost, the app can communicate with the database, only when its launched in heroku that it doesn't seem to be able to communicate with the Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was that heroku wasn't reading this part in the mongoose.connect:

```
'mongodb+srv://admin-cloyd:'+mongoServerPassword+'@todo-app.0pmsv.mongodb.net/toDoDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

I did some more research and in the heroku settings, theres a part that says config vars and what I did was create a variable with the name MONGODB_URL and a value of

```
'mongodb+srv://admin-cloyd:<actual password>@todo-app.0pmsv.mongodb.net/toDoDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

and then I edited my mongoose.connect into this:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL||'mongodb+srv://admin-cloyd:'+mongoServerPassword+'@todo-app.0pmsv.mongodb.net/toDoDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

and it worked. I have no idea why but it works.